# Split a cell with coordinates into two columns with Latitude and Longitude only

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to split a cell with coordinates like `01.00000, 02.00000; 03.00000, 04.00000; 05.00000, 06.00000` into two columns LAT and LONG.
In the first column, all Latitude
In the second column, all Longitude
Like

```
    |  Col A                                                     | Col B                      |    Col C                   |
    |------------------------------------------------------------|----------------------------|----------------------------|
    | 01.00000, 02.00000; 03.00000, 04.00000; 05.00000, 06.00000 | 01.00000,03.00000,05.00000 | 02.00000,04.00000,06.00000 |
```

I use the division formula if only one coordinates are written

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(B1:B)=1,"LNG LTD",IF(ISBLANK(A1:A),"",SPLIT(A1:A, ","))))
```

But I don’t know how to combine the rest now (I don’t really understand how it would be possible to combine everything together with CONCATENATE)

Comment: Is the first piece of raw data in A1 or A2? Do you need to do this for just one cell, or for every cell in Column A?

Comment: And how is the raw data getting into your sheet? Manually or automated? This can be done via formula; I just need to understand the layout and parameters fully.

Comment: Tai, are you interested in the formula solution for this issue? Or are you choosing to use the script version provided by NikkoJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using custom function:

**Code:**

```
function myFunction(value) {
  var result = [];
  value.forEach(val => {
    var lat = [];
    var long = [];
    val.forEach(x => {
      var data = x.split(';');
      data.forEach(x => {
        var temp = x.split(",");
        lat.push(temp[0]);
        long.push(temp[1]);
      })
      result.push([lat.join(","), long.join(",")]);
    })
  })
  return result;
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Reference:**

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)